# TBB Recursive chain reaction with more spawned tasks

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, tbb

What should be done when using Recursive chain reaction in TBB (C++) to determine some values?

For example, when calculating Fibonacci numbers, we are creating two sub-tasks in overloaded execute() method which are: A to calculate n-2.th number and B to calculate n-1.th number. In this example, B is spawned and A is set to spawn_and_wait_for_all (which means that task A is waiting for task B).

But if we, for example, have to determine Tribonacci numbers; then we should have three sub-tasks. My question is, which of these three tasks should be spawn_and_wait_for_all to achieve maximum parallelism?

That question also can be applied when we have **n** sub-tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this primer](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3872.pdf) for background on stalling vs. greedy task scheduling.  In the case of greedy scheduler (e.g. Cilk), the degree of parallelism does not depend on which subtask is issued last.  For a stalling scheduler, scheduling stalls decrease parallelism.  A heuristic for minimizing the number of stalls is to use the biggest subtask for the spawn_and_wait_for_all.  Doing that tends to minimize the chance that the parent thread runs out of work and has to steal from elsewhere, which can result in a stall if the other child tasks complete before the parent thread finishes whatever it stole.

Comment: Thank you very much! Helpful